# how to set bitmap in com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView for android

Tags: android, bitmap

i use com.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView when i set bitmap the picture not appear fully in the view .

this is what i talk about 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cropview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cropview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }, 100);
```